# Disambiguating the [bank] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [bank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bank) tag currently has no summary, [wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bank/info), or [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bank/synonyms).

If you're anything like me, you'd naturally assume that it's referring to [*memory* banks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24557255/4200092), but a quick glance at [the current usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bank) indicates that it's mainly used for questions involving [bank *accounts*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29177913/4200092) or [online payments generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036815/suitable-payment-service)).

My suggestions are as follows:

- Questions about online banking should use the pre-existing [onlinebanking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onlinebanking) tag.
- A new [memory-banks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-banks) tag should be created to unambiguously refer to that topic.
- Homework-style questions asking about [`BankAccount` classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27299372/4200092) don't need to be tagged as such. These tend to be general "how can I make this code work?" questions; the "banking" bit is really just providing a context for the coding problem that has to be solved.

I think that this covers everything, but please leave a comment if you can think of any other potential uses for this tag that should be addressed.

Comment: Wikipedia [has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_%28disambiguation%29), although I don't think any of those could be applied here. I believe this tag should be deleted after cleaning up the questions.

Comment: @JonasCz After looking through that list, I'm reminded that "bank" might be applicable for [questions about 3D rotations](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/36250/banking-an-object-in-relation-to-its-turn.html), though I'm thinking that tags such as [tag:euler-angles] or [tag:quaternions] would cover those cases.

Comment: It is possible that [tag:accounting] might be appropriate if it doesn't involve online transactions (using a computer to perform transactions versus analyzing the transaction data).

Comment: Don't forget there is [tag:banking] too!

Answer (score -5):

If it is being used for finance (which appears to be the norm for its use), could we rename it to *Finance* instead?

I can see why one might flag a question as regarding *Finance* as there are certain consideration that might need to be taken into account (no pun intended).

Comment: Your name outshines every pun you weren't trying to make in your answer.

Comment: Seems to attract down votes.

Comment: Probably because [finance] would be a meta-tag

Comment: OK... are meta-tags bad?

Comment: Yes, [meta tags are bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Wait there is already such a tag. It probably needs to be burninated too.

Comment: Hmm, I would have argued for some tags... but I can see the argument.  [finance] would indicate that the post is subject to financial standards, such as IEEE 754.  That'is a technical requirement, not a subjective opinion.

Comment: AFAIK, IEEE 754 is the floating point standard. I don't know any "finance" standards and I think "finance" is codified as law of individual countries. Furthermore, the tag excerpt of [finance] is non-technical, so it would need to be first cleaned up before a more technical definition can be used.

Comment: Cheers @JeremyBanks!  AFAIK as well, it's just floating points but I figured if there was one, then there will probably be more.  This might be the time that this philosophy is proved wrong though.  *sigh* back to philosophy school.