# Do we currently need the [currency-exchange-rates] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just noticed the [currency-exchange-rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency-exchange-rates) tag and wonder why we need it. It has a potential to attract non-programming inquires.

Currently it has 3 followers, 68 questions, and no description.

Looks like a perfect candidate for burnination to me.

Comment: Rename it to [tag:multi-currency] to cover applications that deal with multiple currencies, including exchange rate processes?

Comment: @NathanOliver - I do not think that we need any business logic - specific tags.

Comment: Yes, I don't use it but now that I know about it I might follow it. It comes up a lot when you have data on your sales in multiple currencies. I mean think about it, you're minding your own business writing code and all of the sudden you need an API to some external live data source just to convert a column of numbers to 1 locale so that you can aggregate it and understand it. Also, some Finance and Economics people study it and also use the other languages popular on SO like `python`, `vba`, `r`, etc.

Comment: @Hack-R - Most of such questions will be off-topic on SO either as "too broad" / "opinion based" or "asking to recommend an external source".

Comment: @PM77-1 That doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: I also would like to know the policy around tags for the use of the code rather than the nature of the technology

Comment: A few months ago I also discovered the [tag:bank] and [tag:banking] tags. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288974/disambiguating-the-bank-tag

Comment: @DidierL Ugg, we really need to break the [tag:bank]! A shame your post didn't get anywhere despite the decent number of votes. Perhaps report as a burninate request?

Comment: It has a description _For questions relating to issues dealing with currency exchange rates. 

Examples include reaching currency exchange API services, converting data, historical analyses of international financial data, etc._

Comment: The phrasing is utterly misleading: **the question asks if we need it, and has +43/-7 upvotes** (including mine), appearing to say "Yes we need it", but is tagged [burninate-request], so some are construing that those are 43 votes to burn it. Also there are 2 answers (and multiple comments) saying it is needed and 0 answers saying it isn't. Do we reword the question? flip the upvotes? close this asking and reask a new one with "Should we burninate..."? cc: @BDL

Comment: I agree with smci: The title in combination with the [tag:burnation-request] leaves the voting results up for interpretation. Since it doesn't answer the usual [burnation request questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate) anyway, I suggest we remove the tag from here and ask a new burnation request for it.

Comment: @BDL: Yes, but also this question needs to be closed as unclear. It will be impossible to retrospectively fix the vote-count based on misleading title.

Answer (score 5):

In view of [Trogdor](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor) I am transferring what I had posted as a Comment:

> *It has a potential to attract non-programming inquires.* Have you checked whether already signs of this? What about these [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate)? Has 66 *Open* Qs (and **4** followers). Seems unambiguous to me.

Basically, if you want a tag burninated please **make a case for doing so**. *potential to attract non-programming inquires* hardly convinces me and I *can* see it being useful to narrow down a search within our 16M+ Qs.

Answer (score -12):

Yes we do need the tag. Citing the same reasons as existing discussion here:

- [it is specific and well-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) (*code/APIs relating* to exchange-rate sites) and [is not a meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)
- it covers a new area. It is not about [currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency). (Anyone who believes it duplicates another topic, please state which topic).
- [it helps sort questions into specific, well-defined categories](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)
- no answer has articulated a reason to delete it (as @pnuts said a month ago, and got no reply)

EDIT: the question was phrased as do we need it? but tagged [burninate-request], my +1 vote (and likely many others) to keep it are locked in. The question is hopelessly confused and should be closed and reasked as an affirmative burninate-request.

Naming: yes it should be called [currency-exchange-rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency-exchange-rates) and not [multi-currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-currency) since that is seriously non-obvious; also the fact that historical exchange rates need to be retrieved/stored/looked-up/used, so [currency-exchange-rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency-exchange-rates) is a perfect name.

([currency-exchange-rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency-exchange-rates) is also useful, since we do not necessarily want individual tags for exchange-rate sites/APIs (e.g. [fixerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixerio))
See [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372489/dont-need-tags-like-fixerio-for-individual-exchange-rate-sites-apis-should). But first we have to resolve this "Should we keep it?" discussion, otherwise that other answer thread is moot.)

Comment: Why do you think that Individual exchange-rate sites and APIs (e.g. fixerio) do not in general deserve their own tag? There are around 40,000 tags in StackOverflow. Still you think  Individual exchange-rate sites and APIs (e.g. fixerio) do not in general deserve their own tag?

Comment: (@IamtheMostStupidPerson: please do not drag in the other discussion, that's specifically why I put it in a different question. Anyway it's moot since this question phrasing is hopelessly confused and should be closed and reasked in the affirmative. First things first.)